# Is it possible to retrieve topic name inside a Lambda function called by an Iot rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I've got a lambda function called by an IoT rule and I would like to know the topic name from inside this lambda function.

So far i'm only able to retrieve the message data from the `event` parameter. Nothing in the `context` parameter neither.

I haven't found anything in the documentation...

Is it even possible ?

Comment: It should be in event object, stringify and log the event when the lambda is invoked  "console.log(JSON.stringify(event))" and see the log in cloudwatch. This might show you where exactly you need to look for topic.

Comment: Nope i've already did that and it's not in the event object...

Answer (score 8):

You need to use topic() function in AWS IoT SQL query. Like this:

```
SELECT * as data, topic() as topic FROM 'desired/+/topic'
```

In this case, your event will include the original message in 'data' field and the used topic in 'topic' field. You can also use integer number as a parameter inside topic() function, to return only sub-group.

More data in oficial documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-function-topic